# Too many categories drastically slow down my website

Tags: categories, query

I'm building a WordPress website that needs something like 7.000 categories. 
I added them, but now I have very long loading times. Pages need something like 30-40 seconds to load completely, and I'm looking for a way to improve that and make the website navigable.

I used Query Monitor to see the queries that slow down my website, and, as I thought, categories are the problem.

Specifically, WordPress struggles to load when querying the database checking for existing categories, using the get_terms() function (which affects 7000 rows). 
I commented that line from taxonomy.php and the website loads normally (with no categories loaded, of course).

The problem is even bigger in the backend.

Now, is there a way I can improve the situation?
Would changing my hosting service, choosing a better one, be a solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 7K hierarchical terms is quite excessive, and will, no matter what, slow your site down dramatically. To be really honest, I do not think changing host will solve your issue, Why do you need so much terms. Looks to a big design flaw to me

Comment: You might be able to fasten the page load with the use of caching plugins / apache_mods and maybe CloudFlare.(But this will only improve backend, not frontend) - You can also optimize your MySQL db, to perform better - but it's not always a webhost will allow it. 

But as Pieter pointed out, this looks like a design flaw.